# Autoparallel submanifolds and geodesics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I have the following question in differential geometry. Any help is greatly appreciated. Let $M$ be an autoparallel submanifold of a manifold $S$ with respect to a connection $\nabla$. Let $\gamma$ be a $\nabla$-geodesic connecting two points $p$ and $q$ of $M$. Should then $\gamma$ completely lie in $M$?

Comment: Can you say what is the precise definition of autoparallel submanifolds?

Comment: Dear @John:I'm following the book Information geometry by Amari and Nagoaka. Having taken a first course on differential geometry, I'm trying to learn this book for my purposes. I haven't taken a course in Riemannian geometry. According to this book, $M$ is an autoparallel submanifold of $S$ iff $\nabla_XY\in \mathcal{T}(M)$ for every $X,Y\in \mathcal{T}(M)$, where $\mathcal{T}(M)$ is the set of all vector fields on $M$. If you can help me understand a bit, it would be great.

Comment: Oh, then it is the same as saying that $M$ is totally geodesics.

Comment: @John: Can you elaborate a bit as an answer?

Comment: I am writing an answer, but your assertion must be incorrect, for example when $M$ is not connected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your definition, you can show that following:

Let $p\in M$ and $v \in T_pM$. Then the geodesic $\alpha$ in $S$ with $\alpha(0) = p$ and $\alpha'(0) = v$ lies completely in $M$.

Proof: Let me use $\bar\nabla $ for the connection in $S$ and $\nabla = \bar\nabla ^\top$ be the connection on $M$ (Which is not the notation you used). Let $\alpha$ be a $\nabla$-geodesic in $M$. Then $\nabla _{\dot\gamma} \dot\gamma = 0$. But as $\gamma$ is in $M$ we have also $\bar\nabla_{\dot\gamma}\dot\gamma = 0$ since by definition

$$\nabla_\dot\gamma \dot\gamma = \big(\bar \nabla_\dot\gamma \dot\gamma\big)^\top$$

and 
$$\big(\bar \nabla_\dot\gamma \dot\gamma\big)^\top = \bar \nabla_\dot\gamma \dot\gamma $$

as $M$ is autoparallel. So $\gamma$ is also a geodesic in $S$. By uniqueness of geodesic, $\gamma = \alpha$. Thus $\alpha$ lies completely in $M$.

However, your assertion is not correct. There are two issues:

1. Topological: Let $S= \mathbb R^2$ and $M$ be two parallel lines. Then for sure your assertion does not hold.
2. Geometrical: Let $S = \mathbb S^2$ and $M$ be the equator in $\mathbb S^2$. Let $p, q\in M$ be two antipodal point in $M$. Then there are infinitely many geodesic containing $p$ and $q$, while only one of them is in $M$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the kind help. I have some questions. What does $T$ stand for in $\bar{\nabla}^T$? And why should $\big(\bar \nabla_\dot\gamma \dot\gamma\big)^\top = \bar \nabla_\dot\gamma \dot\gamma$ if $M$ is autoparallel?

Comment: @Ashok: $T$ denote the projection onto the tangent space of $M$. If $M$ is autoparallel, then all $\bar\nabla_\dot\gamma \dot\gamma$ is in the tangent space of $M$ already, so they are the same

Comment: Thank you @John: I think the result you have proved now is enough for my purposes.

Comment: @John Ma, so a geodesic in an autoparallel submanifold is determined by a point and a "direction" (a vector tangent to the submanifold at the point), rather than by two points in the submanifolds.